# Out of Office G Suite Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to use the following script for my out of office messages but keep receiving the following attached error.

can you tell me how to resolve?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36ETU.png)

Comment: Please learn how to [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and post your code in your question.

Comment: Please provide the code in text, not screenshots.